# Spring Cloud how to register local server to remote eureka server?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We have too many Spring Cloud components, we need to run five or six components every time when at work. The machine is under a heavy load, so I think we can put some components on the remote server, then put some work need components in local. but when I try on this way, the remote server can receive the register from local, But the IP is my local network IP, can't find my local component. What should I do, or there is another way can solve my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your service which IP it should use for the Eureka registration. That's done through the following properties. You can add it to your `bootstrap.yml`

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    ip-address: "${HERE-GOES-YOUR-PUBLIC-IP}"
```

You can inject that IP manually or in config as said before, or reference an environment variable previously set up that contains your public IP.